# How to determine the first day of a month in Python

Tags: python, date, python-2.7

I'm writting (just for fun) a function that prints calendar for any given month and year.
How to determine the first day of a month? Without using the calendar module.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Date manipulation code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157164/python-date-manipulation-code)

Comment: @downvoters: Care to explain (to the OP) what is so bad about the question?

Comment: I guess because you're hating on the one module that was designed for this task to begin with (i haven't downvoted)

Comment: I give an up-vote because it seems to me that Oleg has some curiosity about what's going on under the hood.  But, maybe I'm projecting...

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean week day (monday, ... sunday)?

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime(2017, 11, 2).weekday() # Or another day
3
```

Results from 0 to 6, where 0 is monday.

http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

There's also `isoweekday`, `isocalendar` and other functions/methods in the link above that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to know how the computation is done, and not just what library module to call, the usual method is Zeller's Congruence. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence

That's a neat formula, based on the observation that the days in the months are pretty much regularly-spaced if you view the year as starting in March instead of January.  If you look at the Latin behind the names of the months from September to December, you should see that that indeed is when the year started when the (then Julian, named for Julius Caesar) calendar was devised.

You can also search for that term to find a large number of implementation, of varying quality, in just about every programming language.

Answer (score 1):

H.D's answer is good, if you need the name of the day the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380389/how-to-get-day-name-in-datetime-in-python) should work.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%A")
'Wednesday'
>>>
```